# Thread and loop

Tags: ruby, multithreading, loops

I am trying to write an equivalent to this code:

```
Thread.new do loop do
  ...
end end.join
```

using a class method `Thread.loop` like this:

```
Thread.loop do
  ...
end.join
```

I defined the method as follows:

```
class Thread
  def self.loop &pr; Thread.new{loop{pr.call}} end
end
```

and used it like this:

```
Thread.loop do
  sleep(1)
  puts "foo"
end.join
```

I expected it to be equivalent to

```
Thread.new do loop do
  sleep(1)
  puts "foo"
end end.join
```

but it is not. How can I fix the code?

Is the `loop` inside `Thread.new{}` being interpreted as the method `loop` rather than the keyword? What is the precedence relation between method calls and keywords?

Comment: You just squished `Object.loop`, which is a private method. You're also calling `loop` within `loop` which probably leads to accidental recursion. Patching `Thread` is probably a bad idea. Why not make your own class that does whatever you want?

Comment: @tadman Is there `Thread.loop` prior to my definition? I thought that `loop` was a keyword.

Comment: It's not a keyword, but it is a method that's not supposed to be patched out like that. It exists within `Object`.

Comment: @tadman Thanks. I came up with a solution, following your information.

Comment: that's `Kernel#loop`, isn't it?

Comment: @Stefan Could be. It seems to show up everywhere, which is what Kernel does.

Comment: @Stefan and tadman I see it is indeed `Kernel#loop`. Is it better for me to change `Object` in my answer to `Kernel`? And is `instance_exec` the right method? I cannot think deeply now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tadman and Stefan let me realize that `loop` is a private method on `Kernel`. Considering this, I was able to do it like this:

```
class Thread
  def self.loop &pr
    Thread.new{Object.instance_exec{loop{pr.call}}}
  end
end
```

or as suggested by BroiSatse,

```
class Thread
  def self.loop &pr
    Thread.new{super{pr.call}}
  end
end
```

and it works as intended.

Comment: Why not calling `super` instead of `Object.instance_exec{loop ...}`?

Comment: @BroiSatse You may be right. (Perhaps, I subconsciously had in mind the possibility of someone defining `loop` in a class at somewhere in between, so I thought explicit mentioning would be more robust; I am not sure what I thought subconsciously, just a guess).

Comment: @sawa you don't even need the proc argument: `def self.loop; Thread.new { super }; end`

Comment: You could also do Kernel.loop {...}  - possibly a little easier to read

Comment: @FrederickCheung So it is not private?

Comment: @sawa `Kernel` methods are declared both, as private instance methods and as (public) singleton methods